# Doctrine override relation accessor

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony1, one-to-many

I'm using **Symfony 1.4** + **Doctrine 1.1**.

I have a schema with a one-to-many relation.
Let's say **A** has many **B**, I ask for all the B's of A as follow: 
**`$a->b`**
This returns a **`Doctrine_Collection`**.

What I want is a way to tell Doctrine to give me all the B's of A sorted by a particular attribute of B.

I don't want to re-write the query, I just want to tell the accessor `getBs()` to sort as I wanted.

Is this possible? any idea?

Comment: What you are looking for is http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/cookbook-recipe-relation-dql-behavior It is an example behavior (written by Jon Wage, lead dev of Doctrine), that allows you to include DQL statements into a relation declaration. It's all described in the blogpost so I'll just say I'd recommend putting everything in your `lib/doctrine/` (create it if needed) and there you are!

Comment: Awesome!, just what I needed.
Many thanks Geoffrey

Comment: This solution doesn't work for lazy-loading a relation, only for full DQL Doctrine_Querys (according to a comment by the original author). So, while its useful and nice, it doesn't solve the problem that $a->Bs or $a->getBs() will not produce SQL having an orderBy.

Comment: The link provided in the Geoffrey Bachelet's answer is broken. The updated link is: http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/cookbook-recipe-relation-dql-behavior.html

Comment: What happened with Geoffrey's post is one of the reasons we don't generally accept answers that are primarily links (where you need the link to understand the answer), and try to delete them when we do.

Comment: The second link is also broken